# How to remove duplicates in a data frame using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

So the data  frame is

```
Product    Price  Weight  Range   Count
   A        40      20      1-3     20
   A        40      20      4-7     23
   B        20      73      1-3     54
   B        20      73      4-7     43
   B        20      73      8-15    34
   B        20      73      >=16    12
   C        10      20      4-7     22
```

So basically there is a product with price and weight and the range here specifies the no of days the product was sold continuously and the count specifies the count of products sold in that range

Expected Output

```
Product    Price  Weight  Range   Count
   A        40      20      1-3     20
                            4-7     23
   B        20      73      1-3     54
                            4-7     43
                            8-15    34
   B        20      73      >=16    12
   C        10      20      4-7     22
```

or

```
   Product  Price  Weight  1-3   4-7   8-15  >=16
   A        40      20     20     23   NaN    NaN
   B        20      73     54     43   34     1
   C        10      20      0     22   NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Did you try my solution at all? It's almost the same as the answer you just accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion first solution is not recommended if need processes `DataFrame` later.

Second solution is much better and if duplicates in real data is necessary aggregate values, e.g. by `sum`:

```
#convert catagoricals to strings
df['Range'] = df['Range'].astype(str)

df = (df.groupby(['Product', 'Price', 'Weight', 'Range'])['Count']
        .sum()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
Range Product  Price  Weight  1-3  4-7  8-15  >=16
0           A     40      20   20   23     0     0
1           B     20      73   54   43    34    12
2           C     10      20    0   22     0     0
```

Comment: Something tells me this OP is biased. Two nearly identical solutions, one posted an hour earlier. I bet set index is faster than groupby too, but it seems they don't care. Oh well, you are a lucky man. Enjoy

Comment: its was giving an error:cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category

Comment: i just saw this code:df['Range'] = df['Range'].astype(str) and worked perfectly

Comment: @san Thanks for not telling me about it. I wouldn't know there was an error if you didn't tell me, because I can't read minds.

Comment: sry mate won't happen again no offense

Answer (score 3):

Fulfilling the second output makes more sense than the first. Use `set_index`, followed by `unstack`.

```
(df.set_index(['Product', 'Price', 'Weight', 'Range'])
  .Count
  .unstack(fill_value=0)
  .reset_index()
)

Range Product  Price  Weight  1-3  4-7  8-15  >=16
0           A     40      20   20   23     0     0
1           B     20      73   54   43    34    12
2           C     10     100    0   22     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
mask=df.duplicated(subset=['Product'])
df.loc[mask,['Product','Price','Weight']]=''
```

Output:

```
  Product Price Weight Range  Count
0       A    40     20   1-3     20
1                        4-7     23
2       B    20     73   1-3     54
3                        4-7     43
4                       8-15     34
5                       >=16     12
6       C    10    100   4-7     22
```

.

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Product','Price','Weight'],columns='Range',values='Count').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
Range Product  Price  Weight   1-3   4-7  8-15  >=16
0           A     40      20  20.0  23.0   NaN   NaN
1           B     20      73  54.0  43.0  34.0  12.0
2           C     10     100   NaN  22.0   NaN   NaN
```